# Pygsheet keeps sharing new worksheet IDs with same name

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, pygsheets

I'm trying to use Python to maintain a single report tied to a "title" and share then with specific people. In my code, I try to open my existing sheet report. If it fails in opening I create a new one.

My problem is, this code keeps getting a new ID everytime I do a 'x = client.open(title)', I get a new 'x.id' every time. I debugged and made sure that it was opening and not creating, but still keeps getting a new ID.

This makes it so that multiple versions of this sheet exist since I do a 'x.share' and they all have the same name and appear to have the same history. But looks different with every share. Every share appears to have their own versino because of this unique ID. Edits on previous shares does not apply to the latest share. What can I do here?

```
#########################
## Open/Create GSheet ###
#########################
client = pygsheets.authorize(service_account_file=credsfile)
try:
    gsheet = client.open(title)
except:
    gsheet = client.create(title)
    gsheet = client.open(title)
    gsheet.share('john.doe@gmail.com', role='writer')
```

To test this, run code above and share it to yourself. Edit the first sheet and run the code again. Open that share. It won't have the previous edits you did, but history will show them.

Comment: I proposed an answer by guessing your situation. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your situation and that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike yeah I think you misunderstood it sorry. Thanks for the drive API though. I would dive deep into that if I knew that it was creating instead of opening. But I'm very sure I'm using a single json for authentication given that I only have one service account. I also debugged it and it did the open properly. I'm starting to suspect that the ID changes based on some kind of algorithm of what sheets exist in a worksheet.

I delete and re-create a worksheet and this causes the ID to change (I think). Cause when I changed the delete-add logic into a sheet.clear(), the issue stopped.

Comment: Thank you for quick replying. When my answer was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. In your situation, I thought that you are thinking of Spreadsheet ID. Is my understanding correct? From `I'm starting to suspect that the ID changes based on some kind of algorithm of what sheets exist in a worksheet.`, in your situation, you might be thinking of the sheet IDs in a Google Spreadsheet instead of the Google Spreadsheet ID. At first, I would like to confirm your situation. Can I ask you about your situation?

Comment: @Tanaike you are correct. I am referring to the SpreadsheetID. Google makes it confusing. I think I misunderstood the problem. I think Google is keeping "branches" if versions of a sheet and each branch has it's own spreadsheetID.

What prompted me to open this is that when I edit a previously shared Sheet with me, those updates do not reflect when I run my program again and share it again. If I look into edit history, I can see branches of edit and my manual changes are in one of the branches.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot understand about your actual issue. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your actual issue?

Comment: When I share a sheet to personA, he gets a link he can modify. When I run the program again, it modifies this SAME sheet and shares it again. This time, when you open the link, the changes made by personA is missing. It's not there. When I check the history, the versions kind of branches out and I can only see her changes if I click on her branch

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that in order to replicate your situation, it is required to know more information of your situation. In your situation, who is the owner of Spreadsheet? It's the service account? And, where is the Spreadsheet? It's your Google Drive? About `When I share a sheet to personA`, you manually add the user?

Comment: @Tanaike thanks for the input. I voted to close this question I think I misunderstood how GSheet generally behaved. When I share a link to someone it branches out to it's own version of the doc. Any new edit by a program has to be "shared" again to the users to reflect the most updated version of the doc. This confusing branches of versions of the same worksheet caused my initial confusion

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `Any new edit by a program has to be "shared" again to the users to reflect the most updated version of the doc.`, I cannot understand it. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of it? I would like to confirm your situation.

Comment: @Tanaike when I modify sheet1 to contain letter "A" to cell A1 and share it. Then modify it to "B" in cell A1 and share it again, if I open the link from the first share, the value is still "A".

PS. Who on earth you're top 0.1% what the f...

Comment: Thank you for replying. I thought that I might be able to understand it. For example, in that case, how about using web publish of Google Spreadsheet? [Ref](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308870) In that case, when the Spreadsheet is modified, the latest situation can be seen at the web published Spreadsheet. But if this was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal and your current situation as follows.

- You want to check the existing Spreadsheet using the Spreadsheet title.
- When the Spreadsheet is existing, you want to open the existing Spreadsheet.
- When the Spreadsheet is not existing, you want to create new Spreadsheet and open it.
- You want to achieve this using pygsheets for python.
- You have already been able to use pygsheets.

#### Modification points:

- From `client = pygsheets.authorize(service_account_file=credsfile)`, I confirmed that you are using pygsheets with the service account. In this case, when I consider this and `My problem is, this code keeps getting a new ID everytime I do a 'x = client.open(title)', I get a new 'x.id' every time. I debugged and made sure that it was opening and not creating, but still keeps getting a new ID.`. Spreadsheet of the value of `title` of `gsheet = client.open(title)` might be not existing in the Drive of the service account. If my understanding is correct, this might be the reason of your issue.

  - The Google Drive of the service account is different from the Google Drive of your Google account. When the Spreadsheet of `title` of `gsheet = client.open(title)` is existing in your Google Drive and it tries to search the Spreadsheet using the service account, the service account cannot find the Spreadsheet. In your script, by this, new Spreadsheet is created. In this case, when the Spreadsheet is shared with the email of service account, the service account can find it. I'm worry that this situation might be the reason of your issue.
- And, I thought that in order to check whether the Spreadsheet is existing, Drive API Wrapper of pygsheets can be used. In this case, `try - except` is not required to be used.

  - It seems that `open` medhod also uses the files.list method of Drive API. [Ref](https://github.com/nithinmurali/pygsheets/blob/staging/pygsheets/client.py#L128)

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
title = '###' # Spreadsheet title.
yourEmail = '###' # Your email address.
userEmail = '###' # User's email address.

client = pygsheets.authorize(service_account_file=credsfile)
try:
    gsheet = client.open(title)
except:
    gsheet = client.create(title)
    gsheet.share(yourEmail, role='writer')
    gsheet.share(userEmail, role='writer')
```

or

```
title = '###' # Spreadsheet title.
yourEmail = '###' # Your email address.
userEmail = '###' # User's email address.

client = pygsheets.authorize(service_account_file=credsfile)
res = client.drive.list(q="name='" + title + "'")
if res == []:
    gsheet = client.create(title)
    gsheet.share(yourEmail, role='writer')
    gsheet.share(userEmail, role='writer')
else:
    gsheet = client.open(title)
```

- By sharing the created Spreadsheet by the service account with your Google account, you can see the created Spreadsheet at "Shared with me".

#### Note:

- When you want to open the Spreadsheet existing in your Google Drive, at first, please share the Spreadsheet with the email of the service account. By this, in your script and above modified script, the Spreadsheet is opened and new Spreadsheet is not created.

#### Reference:

- [list(**kwargs) of Drive API Wrapper](https://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/drive_api.html?highlight=drive%20api#pygsheets.drive.DriveAPIWrapper.list)